# Adding a custom printer to Cura

Tags: ultimaker-cura, desktop-printer

I'm trying to enter the settings into Cura for the printer.

The manual has a screenshot of what they should be:

[image: Suggested settings, from manual]

However, when I run Cura and try to enter the settings I'm presented with different options:

[image: Available machine settings (Printer)]

[image: Available machine settings (Extruder 1)]

- How do I translate the settings from teh screenshot into the settings I have available?
- Should I be concerned about the settings that aren't available to enter?

  - Are they important?
  - Do I need to enter them somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Your manual is in another Castle!

The manual you look at is for **Cura (1) 15.04.** You are however using **Ultimaker Cura 3,** most likely the most recent 3.6.

### Quick references

The machine setup is for the [*physical* settings of the machine](https://ultimaker.com/en/resources/52029-manage-printers) - build volume, nozzle diameter, coordinate system and such.

The *other* settings you refer to are [all set in the right bar](https://ultimaker.com/en/resources/52340-quality), but you will have to switch from simple to advanced mode, and possibly activate the settings you need.