# Cura settings for Fabrikator Mini V2 Turnigy or Malyan M100

Tags: ultimaker-cura

I am trying to run this 3D printer:

- Fabrikator Mini V2 Turnigy/Malyan M100

Does anyone have the Cura settings?

Comment: Look [here](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/7696/adding-a-custom-printer-to-cura) for a similar question.

Comment: These setting should come from the manufacturer of the machine.

Comment: The settings of a printer are set in a different section and describe the printer specifics  (bed size, G-code flavor). The profile posted as answers below is a print-profile, it is only valid for something you print on the machine, e.g. in PLA, hence this might not work for ABS as that requires a different profile. This question already [has been asked](/questions/7696/) how to add specific printer parameters in Ultimaker Cura for a printer.

Answer (score 1):

I googled your machine name and found this HobbyKing page.  There is a link here to CURA settings.

[Page with CURA settings](https://hobbyking.com/en_us/mini-fabrikator-v2-3d-printer-us-plug.html)

Answer (score 0):

I thought it better if I included the Cura profile settings, pointed to in [cmm's answer](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/10157/cura-settings-for-fabrikator-mini-v2-turnigy-or-malyan-m100/10166#10166), here, in case of link death:

```
[profile]
layer_height = 0.2
wall_thickness = 0.8
retraction_enable = True
solid_layer_thickness = 1.2
fill_density = 20
nozzle_size = 0.4
print_speed = 60
print_temperature = 200
print_temperature2 = 0
print_temperature3 = 0
print_temperature4 = 0
print_temperature5 = 0
print_bed_temperature = 60
support = Touching buildplate
platform_adhesion = Brim
support_dual_extrusion = Both
wipe_tower = False
wipe_tower_volume = 15
ooze_shield = False
filament_diameter = 1.75
filament_diameter2 = 0
filament_diameter3 = 0
filament_diameter4 = 0
filament_diameter5 = 0
filament_flow = 100
retraction_speed = 30
retraction_amount = 3
retraction_dual_amount = 16.5
retraction_min_travel = 1.5
retraction_combing = All
retraction_minimal_extrusion = 0.02
retraction_hop = 0.0
bottom_thickness = 0.3
layer0_width_factor = 100
object_sink = 0.0
overlap_dual = 0.15
travel_speed = 100
bottom_layer_speed = 20
infill_speed = 0.0
solidarea_speed = 0.0
inset0_speed = 20
insetx_speed = 0
cool_min_layer_time = 3
fan_enabled = True
skirt_line_count = 2
skirt_gap = 4.0
skirt_minimal_length = 150.0
fan_full_height = 0.5
fan_speed = 100
fan_speed_max = 100
cool_min_feedrate = 10
cool_head_lift = False
solid_top = True
solid_bottom = True
fill_overlap = 15
perimeter_before_infill = False
support_type = Lines
support_angle = 60
support_fill_rate = 15
support_xy_distance = 0.7
support_z_distance = 0.15
spiralize = False
simple_mode = False
brim_line_count = 5
raft_margin = 5.0
raft_line_spacing = 3.0
raft_base_thickness = 0.3
raft_base_linewidth = 1.0
raft_interface_thickness = 0.27
raft_interface_linewidth = 0.4
raft_airgap_all = 0.0
raft_airgap = 0.22
raft_surface_layers = 2
raft_surface_thickness = 0.27
raft_surface_linewidth = 0.4
fix_horrible_union_all_type_a = True
fix_horrible_union_all_type_b = False
fix_horrible_use_open_bits = False
fix_horrible_extensive_stitching = False
plugin_config = 
object_center_x = -1
object_center_y = -1

[alterations]
start.gcode = ;Sliced at: {day} {date} {time}
    ;Basic settings: Layer height: {layer_height} Walls: {wall_thickness} Fill: {fill_density}
    ;Print time: {print_time}
    ;Filament used: {filament_amount}m {filament_weight}g
    ;Filament cost: {filament_cost}
    ;M190 S{print_bed_temperature} ;Uncomment to add your own bed temperature line
    ;M109 S{print_temperature} ;Uncomment to add your own temperature line
    G21        ;metric values
    G90        ;absolute positioning
    M82        ;set extruder to absolute mode
    M107       ;start with the fan off
    G28 X0 Y0  ;move X/Y to min endstops
    G28 Z0     ;move Z to min endstops
    G1 Z0.2 F{travel_speed} ;move the platform down 15mm
    G92 E0                  ;zero the extruded length
    G1 X75 E10 F{travel_speed}       ;extrude 10mm of feed stock
    G92 E0                  ;zero the extruded length again
    G1 F{travel_speed}
end.gcode = ;End GCode
    M104 S0                     ;extruder heater off
    M140 S0                     ;heated bed heater off (if you have it)
    G91                                    ;relative positioning
    G1 E-1 F300                            ;retract the filament a bit before lifting the nozzle, to release some of the pressure
    G1 Z+0.5 E-5 X-20 Y-20 F{travel_speed} ;move Z up a bit and retract filament even more
    G28 X0 Y0                              ;move X/Y to min endstops, so the head is out of the way
    M84                         ;steppers off
    G90                         ;absolute positioning
    ;{profile_string}
start2.gcode = ;Sliced at: {day} {date} {time}
    ;Basic settings: Layer height: {layer_height} Walls: {wall_thickness} Fill: {fill_density}
    ;Print time: {print_time}
    ;Filament used: {filament_amount}m {filament_weight}g
    ;Filament cost: {filament_cost}
    ;M190 S{print_bed_temperature} ;Uncomment to add your own bed temperature line
    ;M104 S{print_temperature} ;Uncomment to add your own temperature line
    ;M109 T1 S{print_temperature2} ;Uncomment to add your own temperature line
    ;M109 T0 S{print_temperature} ;Uncomment to add your own temperature line
    G21        ;metric values
    G90        ;absolute positioning
    M107       ;start with the fan off
    G28 X0 Y0  ;move X/Y to min endstops
    G28 Z0     ;move Z to min endstops
    G1 Z0.2 F{travel_speed} ;move the platform down 15mm
    T1                      ;Switch to the 2nd extruder
    G92 E0                  ;zero the extruded length
    G1 X75 E10 F{travel_speed}       ;extrude 10mm of feed stock
    G92 E0                  ;zero the extruded length again
    G1 F200 E-{retraction_dual_amount}
    T0                      ;Switch to the first extruder
    G92 E0                  ;zero the extruded length
    G1 X75 E10 F{travel_speed}       ;extrude 10mm of feed stock
    G92 E0                  ;zero the extruded length again
    G1 F{travel_speed}
end2.gcode = ;End GCode
    M104 T0 S0                     ;extruder heater off
    M104 T1 S0                     ;extruder heater off
    M140 S0                     ;heated bed heater off (if you have it)
    G91                                    ;relative positioning
    G1 E-1 F300                            ;retract the filament a bit before lifting the nozzle, to release some of the pressure
    G1 Z+0.5 E-5 X-20 Y-20 F{travel_speed} ;move Z up a bit and retract filament even more
    G28 X0 Y0                              ;move X/Y to min endstops, so the head is out of the way
    M84                         ;steppers off
    G90                         ;absolute positioning
    ;{profile_string}
start3.gcode = ;Sliced at: {day} {date} {time}
    ;Basic settings: Layer height: {layer_height} Walls: {wall_thickness} Fill: {fill_density}
    ;Print time: {print_time}
    ;Filament used: {filament_amount}m {filament_weight}g
    ;Filament cost: {filament_cost}
    ;M190 S{print_bed_temperature} ;Uncomment to add your own bed temperature line
    ;M104 S{print_temperature} ;Uncomment to add your own temperature line
    ;M109 T1 S{print_temperature2} ;Uncomment to add your own temperature line
    ;M109 T0 S{print_temperature} ;Uncomment to add your own temperature line
    G21        ;metric values
    G90        ;absolute positioning
    M107       ;start with the fan off
    G28 X0 Y0  ;move X/Y to min endstops
    G28 Z0     ;move Z to min endstops
    G1 Z0.2 F{travel_speed} ;move the platform down 15mm
    T2                      ;Switch to the 3rd extruder
    G92 E0                  ;zero the extruded length
    G1 X75 E10 F{travel_speed}       ;extrude 10mm of feed stock
    G92 E0                  ;zero the extruded length again
    G1 F200 E-{retraction_dual_amount}
    T1                      ;Switch to the 2nd extruder
    G92 E0                  ;zero the extruded length
    G1 X75 E10 F{travel_speed}       ;extrude 10mm of feed stock
    G92 E0                  ;zero the extruded length again
    G1 F200 E-{retraction_dual_amount}
    T0                      ;Switch to the first extruder
    G92 E0                  ;zero the extruded length
    G1 X75 E10 F{travel_speed}       ;extrude 10mm of feed stock
    G92 E0                  ;zero the extruded length again
    G1 F{travel_speed}
    ;Put printing message on LCD screen
    M117 Printing...
end3.gcode = ;End GCode
    M104 T0 S0                     ;extruder heater off
    M104 T1 S0                     ;extruder heater off
    M104 T2 S0                     ;extruder heater off
    M140 S0                     ;heated bed heater off (if you have it)
    G91                                    ;relative positioning
    G1 E-1 F300                            ;retract the filament a bit before lifting the nozzle, to release some of the pressure
    G1 Z+0.5 E-5 X-20 Y-20 F{travel_speed} ;move Z up a bit and retract filament even more
    G28 X0 Y0                              ;move X/Y to min endstops, so the head is out of the way
    M84                         ;steppers off
    G90                         ;absolute positioning
    ;{profile_string}
start4.gcode = ;Sliced at: {day} {date} {time}
    ;Basic settings: Layer height: {layer_height} Walls: {wall_thickness} Fill: {fill_density}
    ;Print time: {print_time}
    ;Filament used: {filament_amount}m {filament_weight}g
    ;Filament cost: {filament_cost}
    ;M190 S{print_bed_temperature} ;Uncomment to add your own bed temperature line
    ;M104 S{print_temperature} ;Uncomment to add your own temperature line
    ;M109 T2 S{print_temperature2} ;Uncomment to add your own temperature line
    ;M109 T1 S{print_temperature2} ;Uncomment to add your own temperature line
    ;M109 T0 S{print_temperature} ;Uncomment to add your own temperature line
    G21        ;metric values
    G90        ;absolute positioning
    M107       ;start with the fan off
    G28 X0 Y0  ;move X/Y to min endstops
    G28 Z0     ;move Z to min endstops
    G1 Z0.2 F{travel_speed} ;move the platform down 15mm
    T3                      ;Switch to the 4th extruder
    G92 E0                  ;zero the extruded length
    G1 X75 E10 F{travel_speed}       ;extrude 10mm of feed stock
    G92 E0                  ;zero the extruded length again
    G1 F200 E-{retraction_dual_amount}
    T2                      ;Switch to the 3rd extruder
    G92 E0                  ;zero the extruded length
    G1 X75 E10 F{travel_speed}       ;extrude 10mm of feed stock
    G92 E0                  ;zero the extruded length again
    G1 F200 E-{retraction_dual_amount}
    T1                      ;Switch to the 2nd extruder
    G92 E0                  ;zero the extruded length
    G1 X75 E10 F{travel_speed}       ;extrude 10mm of feed stock
    G92 E0                  ;zero the extruded length again
    G1 F200 E-{retraction_dual_amount}
    T0                      ;Switch to the first extruder
    G92 E0                  ;zero the extruded length
    G1 X75 E10 F{travel_speed}       ;extrude 10mm of feed stock
    G92 E0                  ;zero the extruded length again
    G1 F{travel_speed}
    ;Put printing message on LCD screen
    M117 Printing...
end4.gcode = ;End GCode
    M104 T0 S0                     ;extruder heater off
    M104 T1 S0                     ;extruder heater off
    M104 T2 S0                     ;extruder heater off
    M104 T3 S0                     ;extruder heater off
    M140 S0                     ;heated bed heater off (if you have it)
    G91                                    ;relative positioning
    G1 E-1 F300                            ;retract the filament a bit before lifting the nozzle, to release some of the pressure
    G1 Z+0.5 E-5 X-20 Y-20 F{travel_speed} ;move Z up a bit and retract filament even more
    G28 X0 Y0                              ;move X/Y to min endstops, so the head is out of the way
    M84                         ;steppers off
    G90                         ;absolute positioning
    ;{profile_string}
support_start.gcode = 
support_end.gcode = 
cool_start.gcode = 
cool_end.gcode = 
replace.csv = 
preswitchextruder.gcode = ;Switch between the current extruder and the next extruder, when printing with multiple extruders.
    ;This code is added before the T(n)
postswitchextruder.gcode = ;Switch between the current extruder and the next extruder, when printing with multiple extruders.
    ;This code is added after the T(n)
```

Note these are some customer uploads, from the HobbyKing page for [Mini Fabrikator V2 3D Printer - Silver (US Plug)](https://hobbyking.com/en_us/mini-fabrikator-v2-3d-printer-us-plug.html), under the **Upload Files** tab, click the [`CURA PROFILE_3.ZIP`](https://cdn-global-hk.hobbyking.com/media/file/c/u/cura_profile_3.zip) zip file.